# AUCTeX: Is it possible to allow any value in k=v options?

Tags: auctex

Suppose a `LaTeX` command such as: `\Person[<opt>]{<arg>}` where `<arg>` may be any last name and `[<opt>]` may take several 'named arguments' like so:

```
\Person[function={President of the United States},
        otherinfo={some items of information}]{Roosevelt}
```

Is it possible to define a symbol in AUCTeX that would allow the user to enter those necessarily undefined values in the minibuffer when one is prompted for the accepted keys?

I have tried this so far:

```
(defvar LaTeX-mypackage-person-options
  '(("function")
    ("otherinfo"))
  "Local options.")

;; and then in the hooks

(TeX-add-symbols
    '("Person" [ TeX-arg-key-val LaTeX-mypackage-person-options ]t)
)
```

But infortunately I run into a `no match` warning---as expected---from the minibuffer as soon as I hit the `space` key.  Defining values in `LaTeX-mypackage-person-options` is irrelevant because these values are unpredictable by definition.

Is there a way to define such symbols properly in AUCTeX?

Comment: To whomever downvoted this question: a short comment would have helped me at least to understand why it is devoid of interest!

Comment: I deleted my (wrong) comment and upvoted to counteract the downvote. We start from scratch!  Hope somebody can help you.

Comment: @NickD Thank you!  I couldn't get round this issue.  k=v 'verbose' options are actually processed the same way by many style files.  Try for instance to set hyperref's `pdfauthor`: you will bump into the same `no match` error message as soon as you hit `space` after your first name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design as `minibuffer-local-completion-map` and the derived variable `crm-local-completion-map` both set `SPACE` to `minibuffer-complete-word` and `crm-complete-word` respectively.

You can write a function in your style file which `let`-binds these variables removing the entries for `SPACE`.  E.g., have a look at `graphicx.el` and the definition of [LaTeX-arg-graphicx-includegraphics-key-val](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style/graphicx.el#n80).

In general, you can hit <kbd>C-q SPACE</kbd> if you need a `SPACE` in the minibuffer.  This should suffice for most cases.

Comment: Thanks Arash!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I agree: `C-q SPACE` is quite acceptable for short insertions viz. a couple of words or so.